# Chrome not updating title

Tags: angular, google-chrome, html-title

In an Angular 10 application, I am dynamically setting titles, and in one instance Chrome won't update the text in the tab, but updates `document.title` property just fine. Inspecting page source and the `<title></title>` tag confirms this as well.

This works in other cases in application, and the case in question works fine in browsers with a different engine (Mozilla Firefox and the old Edge). I tested it in Opera and, of course, it doesn't work since the engine is the same.

The code is pretty much straightforward:

```
title: string; // arrives from Observable<>

constructor(public router: Router, private titleService: Title) {
    this.subscriptions.push(router.events.subscribe(() => {                     
        if (this.title)
            this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
    }));
}
```

I've tried setting it directly to `document.title` and also doing both approaches in `setTimeout` with delays form 0.2 to 2 seconds (I've seen that hack somewhere, not that I'm into hacky solutions), with same results.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work, espescially when the page source displays the "correct" title. Have you tried manually changing it?

Comment: I can change it from console and inspected HTML, but it's initially out of sync with devtools.

Comment: does it work as expected with devtools closed?

Comment: Nope. Wish it did though.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue...did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Jadamae77 God, I don't remember, I wasn't the one completing the task. I'll ask my teammates, look through the code, and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: We actually didn't solve it. Not using the router, anyway. We injected the `Title` service on each component we needed to set `<title>` on, and we did it manually :'(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I also had this problem recently. It is not a caching issue. I don't understand why it doesnt update, but you can use the routermodule to overwrite the pagetitle:

```
export const routes: Routes = {
    {path: 'url', component: Component, title: 'title'},
     ..
    }
```

If you like to change the image with it, set another thumbnail image in favicon.ico